# jQuery how to select the first visible textbox, textarea or dropdownlist where no option is selected

Tags: jquery

How to select first visible textbox, textarea or dropdownlist-where no option is selected? The code below is working, but I want make it more generic by not having to use the .firstTextInput class on the first text input.

```
$firstInput = $(this).find('input[type=text],textarea,select').filter(':visible:first');
    if ($firstInput.val() === "") {
        $firstInput.focus();
    }
    else {
        $(".firstTextInput").focus();
   }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can select first visible textbox, textarea via:-

```
$("input[type=text], textarea").eq(0).focus();
```

You can select dropdown using this code:-

```
<select id="test">
  <option value="t1">A</option>
  <option value="t2">B</option>
  <option value="t3">C</option>
</select>

$("#test").val($("#test option:first").val());
```